# Find BTC balance for an address in Go

Tags: go

I need to correct and transform a function, to checking 2 addresses of btc balance, like (addr and addr1 ), and the return is json value, i need to specify im not know very well golang.. need help!

```
func balance(addr) {
    var url = "https://bitcoin.toshi.io/api/v0/addresses/" + addr
    response, _ := http.Get(url)
    defer response.Body.Close()
    contents, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    return contents
}
```

EDIT:

i need a function to get balances of 2 btc addresses, or to use this libraries [btcwallet](https://gowalker.org/github.com/GeertJohan/btcwallet).

```
func GetAddressBalance(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error) 
func GetAddressesByAccount(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error) 
func GetBalance(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error)
```

Comment: It's not too clear what you aim to resolve. Can you reformulate your question?

Comment: i need a function to get balances of 2 btc addresses, or to use this libraries https://gowalker.org/github.com/GeertJohan/btcwallet

Comment: `func GetAddressBalance(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error)
func GetAddressesByAccount(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error)
func GetBalance(icmd btcjson.Cmd) (interface{}, *btcjson.Error) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track. The api returns a json. This can be unmarshalled into a struct (`Address`). That way you can access everything returned by the api. Do not forget to always check for error codes! Replace `some_address` with an actual address to get the balance.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    a, err := getAddress("some_address")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Balance:", a.Balance)
}

type Address struct {
    Hash                string
    Balance             int
    Received            int
    Send                int
    UnconfirmedBalance  int `json:"unconfirmed_balance"`
    UnconfirmedReceived int `json:"unconfirmed_received"`
    UnconfirmedSent     int `json:"unconfirmed_sent"`
}

func getAddress(addr string) (*Address, error) {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://bitcoin.toshi.io/api/v0/addresses/" + addr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error: %v", http.StatusText(resp.StatusCode))
    }

    var address Address
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&address); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return &address, nil
}
```